# How to re.findall() using `daringfireball`'s regex?

Tags: python, regex, url, web-crawler

I have used the code below to extract urls from a html page using `daringfireball`'s regex, http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls, i.e.

> `(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()[]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))`

The regex works amazingly but using `re.findall()` is almost taking forever. Is there anyway that I can get **all** the urls in the html quickly?

```
import urllib, re

seed = "http://web.archive.org/web/20100412111652/http://app.singaporeedu.gov.sg/asp/index.asp"

page = urllib.urlopen(seed).read().decode('utf8')
#print page

pattern = r'''(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))'''

match = re.search(pattern,page)
print match.group(0)

matches = re.findall(pattern,page) # this line takes more than 3 mins on my i3 laptop
print matches
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. By not using regex at all. Use a HTML parser such as [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). That's what they're for.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> import urllib2
>>> seed = "http://web.archive.org/web/20100412111652/http://app.singaporeedu.gov.sg/asp/index.asp"
>>> soup = BS(urllib2.urlopen(seed))
>>> print soup.find_all('a')
```

Comment: but the websites in the other `<x>...<\x>` would have been lost.

Comment: @2er0 You can search for them if you wish. I'm not exactly sure what your expected output is. You did ask for all the links :p

Comment: it's kind of ambitious but it's trying to find all possible urls within a html page =)

Comment: @2er0 What's the result of using the regular expression? I'll try duplicate it, but it could be hard

Comment: actually his regex seems to catch more than url, there's a lot of noise (non-urls) but it seems to be catching all possible urls. it's 20+ mins and it's still running... i've switched to doing this 
`for line in page.split():
 match = re.search(pattern,line)
 if match and "." in match.group(0):
  print match.group(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want all url's from a page? Wouldn't a simple regex like this be sufficient?

```
<a[^>]*href="([^"]+)"[^>]*>
```

Comment: that will give `<a href=...>`, how about url that exist in the text? `<a href>` only gives url in hyperlinks

Comment: @2er0 do all the urls start with http or https? So you could use somthing like (https?:\/\/[^\s"<>]+) . But even better to use a full regex for all valid characters in url instead of my simplified [^\s"<>]. But I guess you have fixed your problem now?